# Запрет доступа к диску и вызов некоторых других функций на уровне Python или Linux

Tags: python, linux, django

Пишу бэкэнд на питоне с использованием джанго и решил добавить функционал, чтобы пользователи могли мне отправлять `.py` файлы на выполнение. Встала задача, как себя обезопасить? Из этого файла я должен вызывать функцию с заранее определённым названием, но проблема в том, что вдруг пользователи внутри функции понаоткрывают сокетов или создадут миллион файлов или ещё чего... В общем, как, вызывая эту функцию запретить им делать это?

Возможно ли сделать это на уровне *питона* а не на уровне *линукса*?

Comment: Можно попробовать добавлять к пользовательскому скрипту некий префиксный скрипт, который задает папки, в которых Python ищет модули, и заменить модули, позволяющие делать опасные операции, на фейковые, которые вместо этого будут вызывать ошибку. Но это один из общих подходов. Не очень знаком именно с Python, к сожалению. Да и в любом случае пользователь может сделать бесконечный цикл (DDoS), то есть его скрипты надо запускать в отдельных потоках с контролем времени их выполнения.

Comment: Невозможно, обязательно найдётся какая-нибудь дырочка

Comment: @andreymal, но как тогда работаю куча сайтов типо яндекс.контест и прочие соревновательные-программисткие?

Comment: На уровне линукса

Comment: @andreymal, не подскажите, как это реализовать на урове линукса?

Comment: @andreymal, вот и не всегда так. большие дяди любят хакать интерпретатор.

Comment: http://m.linuxjournal.com/article/6100?page=0,0, ещё может быть даже хватит пользователя с урезанными правами, который никуда не сможет писать, ниоткуда читать и ничего исполнять, кроме python

Comment: Если уж совсем безопасно - запускайте в контейнере (docker) и все. Вобще никуда доступа не будет, если сами не подключите локальную файловую систему.

Comment: На уровне питона можно оставить только список разрешенных функций и вызов, свой разбор. Но достаточно трудоемко и получим урезанный вариант pypy или велосипед интерпретатора.

Comment: PyPy умеет [сэндбоксить](http://doc.pypy.org/en/latest/sandbox.html) скрипты.

Comment: Никто не вспомнить про чрутинг? Вот, [чрутинг](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chroot). Но с докером получится сделать быстрее и красивее, и там можно лимиты выставлять. Если будет интересно, кину пример как это сделать.

Answer (score 3):

PyPy предлагает песочницу на уровне схожем с уровнем ОС песочниц, например SECCOMP под Linux, но это чисто решение на уровне питона:

> One of PyPy’s translation aspects is a sandboxing feature. It’s “sandboxing” as in “full virtualization”, but done in normal C with no OS support at all.

Подробнее с примерами в [документации к PyPy](http://doc.pypy.org/en/latest/sandbox.html).